# app icon appears on app simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, icons

I have my six Icon.png - Icon-Small@2x.png files in my project and they are listed the same way in my plist just like I have read. My icons show up when I run my app in the simulator, but not when I run it on my device.

I am using xcode 4.5.2 and am running the apps on my iPhone 4s.

Comment: Does xcode give you an error when you try building on a device?

Comment: Most likely your actual image filenames don't exactly match. Make sure  the filenames are really Icon.png and not icon.png, etc. The device is case-sensitive, the simulator isn't.

Answer (score 2):

@Fernando Mazzon 's long shot has helped me. In my case I have renamed jpeg into png with this problem occuring. After I choose to export jpeg to png(this time for sure it is png), it works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the app from your device and re-run from XCode.

Comment: + clean & clean build folder

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Simulator is case-sensitive, while actual iOS devices are not.  Check that the case matches between your actual filenames and what you have specified in your `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning, resolution modifiers, case sensitiveness, and:
This is a long shot, but PSDs renamed to PNGs are taken by the emulator silently, whereas the device, understandably, doesn't take them. This is quite annoying and hard to track. Check if you have concealed PSDs as icons if everything else fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The Icon.png file was not 57 by 57 pixels.  The icon loaded in the simulators but not on the iPhone.

After I resized the icon file to 57x57 (and the Icon@2x.png file to 114x114), my app icon showed up on the device.